# Exclude some folder to be swapped in Azure Web app

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, swap

I've a PHP azure web application ( custom docker image / linux , with two slot : production and pre-prod ) , each contains it's own logs.

the problem is : when swap, all folder will be swapped including the log file , so , the log of production slot will be swapped to pre-prod slot and vise-versa

it's possible to exclude a particular folder ? because file mapping settings is swapped and no option to set , to be specified to slot.

Thanks.

Comment: You may try to externalize the data into Azure Storage blob or a database, As the Slots means two different sites, and all the files they contain get swapped.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are asking for currently doesn't exist in deployment slots. As Jason recommended in this [Github post](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/80131), you can try sending the logs to Azure Monitor. If you write the logs to standard output you can use the feature below to route them to a storage account or log analytics

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#send-logs-to-azure-monitor-preview